# jboss-as-maven-plugin can't deploy to remote JBoss AS7?

Tags: java, deployment, maven, jboss

I've tried for days to use `jboss-as-maven-plugin` to deploy web projects to remote JBoss AS7, but it didn't work.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- JBoss Application Server -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0.CR1b</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- Only remote server needs -->
            <configuration>
                <hostname>192.168.1.104</hostname>
                <port>9999</port>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin123</password>
            </configuration>
        </execution>    
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Using this configuration I can deploy to **localhost** without `<configuration>`, even no `<username>` and `<password>`.

To deploy to my real IP address, I modified **${JBOSS_HOME}/configuration/standlone.xml**, by changing `jboss.bind.address` from **127.0.0.1** to **0.0.0.0** (to unbind JBoss address), so I can deploy projects by using:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- 192.168.1.106 is my ip -->
    <hostname>192.168.1.06</hostname>
    <port>9999</port>
</configuration>
```

It works too, but by changing `<hostname>` to point to my other computer (in the same router) it doesn't work but that computer receives a request, and the request is cut by something. (I thought it may be JBoss)

The error message in Maven console is as follows:

```
 INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.CR8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30.572s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 10 23:41:25 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.1.0.
CR1b:deploy (default) on project MessagePushX-RELEASE: Could not execute goal de
ploy on MessagePush.war. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could no
t connect to remote://192.168.1.104:9999. The connection timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Who can tell me is JBoss as 7.1.0 is not allowed remote deploy?

For some security issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely not a security issue.

The plugin you are referring uses the JBoss AS7 ability to deploy applications using the Server Deployment Manager (this is new feature in AS7). [Previously](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/) the deployment was only possible via JMX console, which required the deployment artifact to be reachable by server (local file or URL).

You need to make sure:

- 192.168.1.104 is running JBoss AS7 with Server Deployment Manager listening on port 9999.
- The port should not be bound to localhost iface (not 127.0.0.0:9999 but *:9999).
- There is no firewall between you and 192.168.1.104 rejecting packets to port 9999.

Comment: Tank you,finally I found something solved my problem.Jboss AS 7 use JMX to deploy application.So we should  open ${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml ,and locate this  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">  and add  <jmx-connector registry-binding="jmx-connector-registry" server-binding="jmx-connector-server"/> in it.It  can make jboss-as-maven-plugin works.

Comment: solution in the comment above didn't work for me, just got parse errors when adding it to my standalone.xml

Answer (score 6):

what worked for me was to change from jboss-as plugin to wildfly plugin:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0.Alpha8</version>
 </plugin>
```

and then using the maven command:

```
mvn wildfly:deploy
```

reference: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3684

Comment: with the actual version

Comment: Actually this is the solution

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when configuring the plugin with the hostname parameter "127.0.0.1" as the server seems to bind to that IP by default:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                  <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, using the last version of plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.5.Final</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remote deployment definitely works.

1. Be sure that management port (native) is bound to *.9999, as mentioned above .

   ```
   <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${*:9999}"/>
   ```
2. Be sure that you added user to management realm. Also, I noticed that password was cached the first time I ran plugin, so later on it keep using stale password (from first run) instead of new one. I notice this using mvn -X option.
3. I also turned off firewall on jboss server host machine. At least ports 8787, 4447, 8080, 9990 must be opened.

Here is complete plugin declaration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.Final</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <force>true</force>
        <hostname>IP</hostname>
        <port>9999</port>
        <username>mvndeploy</username>
        <password>pa##word1.</password>
        <filename>${project.build.finalName}</filename>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Test everyting with :

```
mvn package jboss-as:deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

Use wildfly-maven-plugin instead of jboss-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked changing the version of the maven plugin to the newer:

```
 <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got the same error by using IntelliJ I undeployed the project from JBoss server and again deployed it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs due to binding address of your JBOSS, if you will take a look at standlone.xml the jboss management bind address is

> jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1

You can change it to the machine IP adress or point it to 0.0.0.0

> jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0/machine IP

restart JBOSS and try mvn jboss plugin should work like a charm.